# Pulling unique sets of data stored in SQL Server 2008 R2 using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I have groups of data (using a parameter name to group) and need to pull all unique values. The database table has two columns, `ParameterName` and `ParameterValue`. I'm looking for a way to generate

For example:

- Age: 27, 36, 42 (3 records)
- Color: Red, White Blue, Purple (4 records)
- Flower: Rose, Orchid, Lily (3 records)
- Object: Shoes, Gloves (2 records)
- Sex: Male, Female (2 records)

Desired Result:

- 27, Red, Rose, Shoes, Male
- 36, Red, Rose, Shoes, Male
- 42, Red, Rose, Shoes, Male
- 27, White, Rose, Shoes, Male
- 36, White, Rose, Shoes, Male
- 42, White, Rose, Shoes, Male

.....
and so on.  Any help would be appreciated.  I feel like this should be simple, but nothing has hit me yet...not even the structure

Comment: No offend, but if you feel like this should be simple, please try to to do it, and if you got stuck or a problem, you can post it here, `Stackoverflow` is not a platform for giving code away.

Comment: I have; for 3 days now.  And believe me, I would not post here if I wasn't truly stuck. I'm the only programmer here and though that using one of these forums would help to bounce ideas around....just for logic...not even code.  Maybe I have the wrong forum.  I don't know.

Comment: Ahh, the notorious [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) anti pattern... It's so tempting to use since it seems so easy at first glance, but then when you get to query it you can drive yourself insane.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [age].ParameterValue as [age]
     , [color].ParameterValue as [color]
     , [flower].ParameterValue as [flower]
     , [object].ParameterValue as [object]
     , [sex].ParameterValue as [sex]

FROM ( SELECT * FROM [tblParameters] where ParameterName = '[age]' ) [age]  
  CROSS JOIN ( SELECT * FROM [Vignette].[dbo].[tblParameters] where ParameterName = '[color]' ) [color]  
  CROSS JOIN ( SELECT * FROM [Vignette].[dbo].[tblParameters] where ParameterName = '[flower]' ) [flower]  
  CROSS JOIN ( SELECT * FROM [Vignette].[dbo].[tblParameters] where ParameterName = '[object]' ) [object]  
  CROSS JOIN ( SELECT * FROM [Vignette].[dbo].[tblParameters] where ParameterName = '[sex]' ) [sex]
```